# How do I retain a new strings value during a loop, continuously changing the string until the loop ends?

Tags: python-3.x, string, immutability, str-replace

I want to take the value of a string and loop, asking the user to choose single character replacement during each loop iteration. I want to retain the changes the user makes to the string and then make an additional replacement which is also retained until the user chooses to end the loop.

```py
newtext = ''
ciphertext = 'qsv el arm aepm sh tzz ussx pmb as dspm as arm tex sh armel dsvbaci.'
answer = 'y'

for letter in ciphertext:
    while answer is 'y':
        print(ciphertext)
        cl = input('Which letter would you like to replace? ')
        rl = input('What is the new letter? ')
        newtext += ciphertext.replace(cl,rl)
        print(newtext)
        answer = input('Would you like to continue? (y/n) ')
```

Comment: You want to keep a history of changes to the string? What have you tried so far to do that?

Comment: Not exactly.... say the cipher text is ixv. I change i to "t". Now the cipher text becomse txv. Next loop i choose to change x to "h", now the cipher text is thv. Finally, I change the letter v to "e" and the cipher text is now "the". The user works through manual substitutions until the text is deciphered, then they choose to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do like this:

```
original = 'qsv el arm aepm sh tzz ussx pmb as dspm as arm tex sh armel dsvbaci.'
ciphertext = 'qsv el arm aepm sh tzz ussx pmb as dspm as arm tex sh armel dsvbaci.'
newtext = ''
answer = 'y'


while answer is 'y':
    print(ciphertext)
    cl = raw_input('Which letter would you like to replace? ')
    rl = raw_input('What is the new letter? ')
    newtext = ciphertext.replace(cl,rl)
    print(newtext)
    answer = raw_input('Would you like to continue? (y/n) ')
    if(answer == "y"):
        ciphertext = newtext
    else:
        ciphertext = original
```

I changed a little bit your code. If you need any clarification lemme know

**UPDATE**

```
original = 'qsv el arm aepm sh tzz ussx pmb as dspm as arm tex sh armel dsvbaci.'
plaintext = 'qsv el arm aepm sh tzz ussx pmb as dspm as arm tex sh armel dsvbaci.'
answer = 'y'
replacements = {}


while answer is not 'q':
    print(plaintext)
    cl = input('Which letter would you like to replace? ')
    rl = input('What is the new letter? ')
    x = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(original) if ltr == cl]
    replacements[cl] = x
    plaintext = list(plaintext)
    for i in replacements[cl]:
        plaintext[i] = rl
    plaintext = "".join(plaintext)
    print plaintext
    answer = input('Would you like to continue? (y/n) ')
    if(answer == "n"):
        plaintext = original
```

This should be good! Lemme know.
I'm aware about the `raw_input` problem, i changed to input for a faster "debugging".
Sorry but i didn't understand before the problem correctly :P

Comment: Thanks Benny, that helps. You will always want to use input() now in python 3.x instead of raw_input(), security risk because raw_input() will accept things it should not. You helped me get to the next problem, each answer in the loop will keep changing all of the text, not retaining the replacements but 'replacing the replacements' LOL. Closer... thanks for your help.

Comment: Your edit was perfect.... I fixed my ciphertext, had a dup..., and tweeked the loop exit. Now I can perfect the rest. Thank you,  I learned a lot with your help!

Comment: No problem, if i solved your problem, please accept the answer.